# Is there a function to select a particular part of a string based on searching for a word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select part of a string starting from a specific word that will always be present in the fields

So here is an example of what the field may look like: 
"Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - History"

I only want to capture the file path which is "Enterprise:Human Resources:Test"

For example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - 
History', 17, 32) AS ExtractString;

Result = Enterprise:Human Resources:Test
```

The problem with this select statement is that it only works for this particular example as the substring start and length will be subject to change.

Comment: So you want to capture everything between '-' and '-'?

Comment: What DB brand are you using?

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Skye, my answer below should solve your problem. Please accept the answer if it does!

Comment: you should show examples that are giving wrong results instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use charindex.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - History',
CHARINDEX('-','Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - History')+1, 
CHARINDEX('-','Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - History',CHARINDEX('-','Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - History')+1) -CHARINDEX('-','Admin use only - Enterprise:Human Resources:Test - History')-1)
```